# Windows 7 freezing in XP mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

I've used XP mode on Windows 7 for half a year, but of late it has been freezing with a black screen. I can't even shut it down by changing the configuration of the close button. Tell me how I can shut it down.

Comment: Just to be clear, the XP mode VM guest OS is freezing, right, and not the host Windows 7?

Comment: If host is not freezing then open task manager and kill the VM application.

Comment: Host is not freezing.I tried kill VM application and restarted it as avirk said.But Situation hasn't changed screen is still black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this the suggestions from here:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/xp-mode-blank-screen-dimmed-out-enable-integration/5c1cf016-773c-4304-9be3-45b615e04d82

> I found that I didn't have to remove the .VMC file, **but rather jsut the .VSV file which is the saved state of the machine**. Then, I didn't have to recreate the virtual machine.

Comment: I tried but　I can’t remove VSV file and also VMS file. I think files have been under execution, the XP mode process has’t finish yet.

Comment: kill the VPC.exe first with Taskmgr/ProcExp

Comment: I did.But files havn't been relesed.

Comment: Use ProcessExplorer and search for open handles to this file and close those handles.

Comment: I can find process's name VMWindow.exe  but can't find open handles .Are there some special view for searche them?

Comment: use CRTL+F in ProcExp and search for the .VSV file and close all the handles to the VSV file.

Comment: The steps I recovered from thia trouble is kill process and close all the handles to the VSV file with Process Explorer as magicandre1981 said ,then rename .VSV file. Actually I reuse .VSV file after making sure XP mode restart normally.